# Compress and decompress

Tags: code-golf, compression, open-ended-function, self-referential

Your task is to make a bidirectional compressor. It takes a list of bytes as input and returns a list of bytes as output. It has the property than whenever it is iterated twice it returns the original input.

In other words, if `f` is your program as a function, then `f(f(x))=x` for all `x`.

Now, since this is a "compressor", it should actually try to compress it's input. Of course, it can't compress every input. It should however be able to compress your program's source code. That is, if `s` is your program's source code, then `len(f(s))<len(s)`.

To recap, your program acts as a function that takes a list of bytes as input and outputs a list of bytes as output. Let's call your program `f` and it's source code `s`. Your program must satisfy both:

- `f(f(x)) = x` for all `x`
- `len(f(s)) < len(s)`

Remember that the empty list is a list, and thus your code should be able to handle it.

Normal quine rules apply, so no introspection is allowed (opening the file that contains your source code, etc.).

Shortest code wins!

Comment: Why does this seem easier than it actually is?

Comment: Is it introspection to use JavaScript's built-in method for handling functions as strings?

Comment: @ThisFieldIsRequired Yes

Comment: i wonder how long the unary answer is

Comment: @ThisFieldIsRequired because he didn't say you can't use builtins for the compression :)

Answer (score 11):

## JavaScript (ES6), 26 bytes

*-1 thanks to @thejonymyster*

*-7 thanks to @Arnauld*

*-4 thanks to @l4m2*

```
x=>x.replace(/-2|1/,z=>~z)
```

Swaps the first instance of `-2` and `1`, saving 1 byte when the program compresses itself. Takes the list of bytes as input, as a string.

This is quite the community effort now :p

Comment: [28](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/Z9m@7/C1q5Cryi1ICcxOVVD39KixlBfp8rWztJSt0rzf3J@XnF@TqpeTn66RrGCrUKaRppeSX5wSVFmXrqGpqYmF7KCNI1iDBElj9ScnHwFQyVcMgU5QKn/AA)

Comment: [26](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/Z9m@7/C1q5Cryi1ICcxOVVDX9eoxlBfp8rWrq5K839yfl5xfk6qXk5@ukaxgq1CmkaaXkl@cElRZl66hqamJheygjSNYgwRJY/UnJx8BUMlXDIFOUCp/wA)

Comment: [25](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/Z9m@7/C1q5Cryi1ICcxOVVDX9feUF@nytZOt0rzf3J@XnF@TqpeTn66RrGCrUKaRppeSX5wSVFmXrqGpqYmF7KCNI1iDBElj9ScnHwFQyVcMgU5QKn/AA)

Comment: `/-?1/,z=>-z` fail if input contain `--1` and was deprecated

Comment: @l4m2 Good point, that's the same thing that messed up my `y"` earlier

Comment: But the 26 should work

Comment: The byte count is wrong now.

Answer (score 5):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>102</s> 59 bytes

```r
function(x)`if`(nchar(x)%%2,sub("#$","",x),sub("$","#",x))#
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/qfZvs/rTQvuSQzP0@jQjMhMy1BIy85I7EIyFFVNdIpLk3SUFJWUdJRUtKp0IRwQTxlEFdT@X9uZUFRfrqtOgVmqHOlaUCM0QSy4GxNLi5lheSM1OTsYisUcVtbCEtBWSEkKNSVC2IVQt4GIgDlQlX9BwA)

`f()` removes any trailing `#` comment character if there are an odd number of characters in the input (as in `myprog`), or adds one if there are an even number.

([Removing the first `f`](https://tio.run/##K/qfZvs/rTQvuSQzP0@jQjMhMy1BIy85I7EIyFFVNdIpLk3SUIpT0lFKU9Kp0IRygWwlEFfzf25lQVF@uq06@Uaoc6VpQEzRBLLgbE0uLmWF5IzU5OxiKxRxW1sIS0FZISQo1JULYhNC3gYiAOVCVf0HAA) would also work, and is 1-byte shorter, but it's less satisfying as the 'compressed' function is no longer a runnable compression function itself...)

Answer (score 3):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 49 bytes

```c
A;f(char*s){s[-1]=65;A=s[A=*s==65]-59?s:s-1+A*2;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/9/ROk0jOSOxSKtYs7o4Wtcw1tbM1NrRtjja0Var2BbIidU1tbQvtirWNdR21DKyrv0PUq1QXFIUbWhgEGvNpZySmpaZlwoSUdAAEtommlyZeSUKuYmZeRqaCtVcCkAAFE8uqARJ6ygoGRoZm5gqaVqDZQpKS4o10kAymlARFLWO1qSoxqe49j8A)

[Surculose Sputum's idea](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/241354/)

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>55</s> <s>54</s> 52 bytes

```c
A;f(char*s){A=*s-(s[-1]=65)?s-1:*++s-65?s:f(s+1)-2;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lYuxCoMwFEV3vyLYJc80YKxxMIjkO8RBUtNmMIjPDkX89tSULl0KfcMdzjnP8JsxIWhlqbkPS4aw6SZDTrHjom8qCS1yUWeMIa9ki7WlyATwQu0hPhBcl07kea@S03W0zo@REHoMKyFxfiXT4DwFsiXkuIOb@Rn1maSiuJQyBfU282NFaqOBD/lq9V/xr3oPLw)

Thank gastropner for -2 bytes

Requires `s[-1]` be writable

Comment: [52 bytes](https://tio.run/##lYuxCoMwFEV3vyLYJc80YKxxMIjkO8RBUtNmMIjPDkX89tSULl0KfcMdzjnP8JsxIWhlqbkPS4aw6SZDTrHjom8qCS1yUWeMIa9ki7WlyATwQu0hPhBcl07kea@S03W0zo@REHoMKyFxfiXT4DwFsiXkuIOb@Rn1maSiuJQyBfU282NFaqOBD/lq9V/xr3oPLw)

Answer (score 2):

## [Zsh](https://www.zsh.org/), 35 bytes

```
printf %s ${1/(#m)(-3|2)/$[~MATCH]}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m724qjhjwdaSIgXdFIWYmDwbG_XU_DR1u-T8lNSlpSVpuhY3lQuKMvNK0hRUixVUqg31NZRzNTV0jWuMNPVVout8HUOcPWJroUqvAvVycRWV5mloJufn5ibmpSgAjVfQVdHNV0itKEnNS0lNSc_JT1IAGa-gpGKoxMVlA-ZYK6QmZ-SDtAKFNSBimkqoomiScGmwvDEyxwhJoy6KjC6KFJocmiRMFuK5BQsgNAA)

Previous version [independently discovered to l4m2's golf to Redwolf's answer, goddamn ninjas!](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/60184082#60184082) (now just a lazy port :/)

Swaps the first instance of `-3` for `2` and vice versa.

Answer (score 2):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 37 bytes

```apl
'¯2|1'⎕R{⍕83⎕Dr~11⎕Dr⍎⍵.Match}⍠'ML'1⊢
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT////1Hf1EdtE9QPrTeqMVQHcoKqH/VOtTAGslyK6gwNwfSj3r5HvVv1fBNLkjNqH/UuUPf1UTd81LUIKPn/v4K6OlQ30dpB@sEGKKg/6p2rUFKeDzREIS2/SCG1ODmxIDMvXUFdITNPoSQjFUgVlJYoAAA)

Same thing as everyone else here has done replaces ¯1 with 1 and vice versa

and it works this time for sure :D

Comment: This doesn't work. applying the function to the compressed string needs to return the original string. `¯1 => 1 => ¯1`

Comment: fixed it @thejonymyster

Comment: fails for `¯¯1` (`¯¯1` => `¯1` => `1`)

Answer (score 1):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), 18 bytes

```
1`-1|(2)
$#1$*-$.&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/P/fMEHXsEbDSJNLRdlQRUtXRU8NmxgA) Explanation: Port of @RedwolfPrograms' JavaScript answer.

```
1`
```

Only replace the first match.

```
-1|(2)
```

Match `-1` or `2`.

```
$#1$*-
```

Output `-` only if `2` was matched.

```
$.&
```

Output the length of the match.

Answer (score 1):

## Haskell, 54 bytes

```
f('l':')':l)='!':l;f('!':l)="l)"++l;f(x:l)=x:f l;f_=[]
```

[Try it Online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P01DPUfdSl1T3SpH01ZdEUhZA4UUwVylHE0lbW2QQAWIW2GVpgDkxNtGx/7PTczMsy0oLQkuKVJJU1HCZ0oM0JgYHOYo/QcA)

Switches the first occurrence of `l)` and `!`.

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 48 bytes

*Thanks @AnttiP for pointing out the error in a previous version.*

```python
lambda s:['l'+s,s[1:],s][('l'+s[:2]).find('la')]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fZC9TsMwFIV3P8WhHRKLqBIgMURkYGFi7IAURcgk142RY0e2Q@nTBydNpFIkJvt@99y/059Ca83DWNuGUGCz2YxadB@NgM/LRCe3PvPlXV5lvirTOS7z@4rvpDJNjEXCqzEW7Xxwqk85Y1vs3QlHFVqEliAHUwdlDeYBwkOZfghMxln0JXQ6Yc5q2/WOvKcmcrnAhv7gNeSsd8qERbj@r7OXDVZ23pB8OK8otMa0ujl4WAlN5hDpEx5xbMkRSNQt6lY4UQdyUB4Uy@LvNcMzrMMbk852UDEbrNXxvq63LqB3thnqwOKA9@CGydt9fJiMNSaaACfMgdJHnjNggpMza1WaCP2dZI56EqEwswZRUSBJdp9WmdTzGV0ZtNB/jZsESsZmN8Uv4XkGsD37tLQCLg54EdrT4uOK@fgD)

Takes in a string and compress/decompress it.

- If the input starts with `a`, prepends `l`
- If the input starts with `la`, then remove the first character `l`.
- Otherwise, returns the input unchanged

`('l'+s[:2]).find('la')` evaluates to 0, 1, -1 for each of the above case respectively. This is because by prepending `l` to the first 2 characters, we get `l??`. If we find `la` at the 0th index (`la?`), then the first character of input must be `a`. If we finds `la` at the 1st index (`lla`), then the input must starts with `la`.

Comment: This fails for input "ll"